# Django Row Number in Pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination

Is there a way in getting the row number for items displayed in Paginator? For example, i set that a page should contain 50 items so, the next page row number should start at 51. However I cannot find any way to do this, and when I use `forloop.counter` the row number resets every page.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#add) template tag to add the current count from the paginator to the forloop

```
{{ forloop.counter.0|add:paginator.page.start_index }}
```

Comment: this is the solution! However, use `forloop.counter0` instead. Awesome!

Comment: thanks, however in my case(using ListView) it was ```{{forloop.counter0|add:page_obj.start_index}}```.